# Is there a probability that a neutrino and anti-neutrino transform into two photons?

Tags: photons, neutrinos, electroweak

A neutrinos and an anti-neutrino can meet, form a virtual $Z^0$, which subsequently can create a new pair of leptons.

Now, an electron-anti-electron pair can do the same, but they can create two photons too.

Can a neutrino and anti-neutrino do the same, by a second-order process? Say by creating a virtual $W^-$ and a $W^+$ (coupling to a loop) which create two photons (somewhat like two photons coupling to an electron loop creating two photons in photon-photon scattering)?

Answer (score 6):

Basically yes, with a twist. The Z can decay to a neutrino-antineutrino pair, as you may verify from its nontrivial PDG-couplings in the SM. Conversely, their fusion may result in a (virtual) Z.

The Z would rather go to three γs, at the [1-loop level](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(91)91846-N), as the coupling to 2γs is suppressed by [Yang's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Yang_theorem) (a Bose-symmetry argument).

So, indeed, $\nu \bar\nu \to 3\gamma$.

Comment: Isn't the $\nu\bar\nu$ cross-section really tiny? How much energy do they need for these interactions to occur with a probability high enough for us to detect them?

Comment: Oof... this is a much broader question, not one of principle asked in the OP. The cross section depends on the energy, as you point out, but the coupling itself is respectable, as you recall from studies of the Z at LEP. So if you were near the Z pole.... The coupling to the photons is 1-loop, not tree, and of course also depends on the energy....

Comment: @ErnieB [Here](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-standard-model.pdf), worth knowing (10.2) & (10.5a,b) by heart. I'd be alarmed if your HEP course did not dwell on this.

Comment: How can a Z decay to three photons? Can't the both neutrinos couple to a virtual W+ and a W- which each create a real photon (which would mean a W partially running in a loop, i.e. three sides, the low side being a neutrino; is that possible?)? Or is this the suppressed mechanism?

Comment: Did you read the paper I linked? It has the very loop you are asking about. Bypassing the intermediating Z in favor of an external  nu nubar gammas loop is allowable.

Comment: Ah! Okay. Thanks. So a neutrino antineutrino pair can couple to a W-W+ pair (which can give two photons)? (Just to be clear)

Comment: Indeed, you may have $\nu \bar \nu$ go into a loop with $e W^+  $ which may couple to 2 photons. This is a very different question than the OP. Ultimately, if one specified initial and final products, one needs compute *all* diagrams, including the ones discussed, to make sure which contribute to what and which dominate....

Comment: What  are the $T^+$ and $^T-$ in 10(2) in the article you linked? (in front of the $W^+$ and $W^-$). It's a great formula!

Comment: They are (probably, up to a normalization) the raising and lowering Pauli matrices of weak isospin, $T^+= \tau^+ /2= (\tau^1+i\tau^2)/4=  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}/2$, and its hermitean conjugate...

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks. The reason I asked the question is because in the CCC model of Penrose, all matter is supposed to end up in photons but I can't imagine the whole neutrino background radiation  to be absorbed by black holes. So if the black holes emit enough anti-neutrinos, maybe they could annihilate with all neutrinos via the eW loop into photons.